# Upgrade Xcode8 with Swift3.0?

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Recently, I have upgraded my Xcode to version8, some strange errors are appear in my console like below:

```
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)
Painter Z index: 1023 is too large (max 255)    
ERROR /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit_Sim/VectorKit-1228.30.7.17.9/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1763: InfoLog SolidRibbonShader:
ERROR /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit_Sim/VectorKit-1228.30.7.17.9/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1764: WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'v_gradient' not read by fragment shader
```

Any expert know how to deal with it?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I saw the same thing when pushing to a VC with an inputAccessoryView in ios10 in xcode 8. Doesn't occur when I remove the inputAccessoryView from the VC

Comment: My VC don't have any inputAccessoryView.

Comment: Also seen the error when a MapView is present

Comment: May be this will be helpful : `https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/cant-see-any-segmented-control/11165/2`